# Change Date format for generated scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I want the date to be day, month, year. i.e. Jan 1, 2015. How can I change the format to this and what file should I put it in?

I want the date to show up in this format within **index.html.erb** and in the **_form.html.erb**.

I accidentally did a scaffold as datetime, but manually changed everything back to date, then ran rake db:reset. Now when I create something the date comes up as: 2014-12-31 00:00:00 UTC.

Thanks for any help you could give me!

Comment: You need to post both your view and controller code. I don't know what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) to format your dates into formatted strings.

```
DateTime.now.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
```

**Edit**

In a rails view

```
<%= DateTime.now.strftime("%d/%m/%y") %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just don't know where to put that code and I don't think I want to use DateTime I want to use Date. Somehow I've gotten this index to look like this now: 2014-12-31 I would be happier if I could just get it to look like this though at this point: 12-31-2014, ideally, Dec 31, 2014.

Comment: Are you saying you want to display the current date on a view?

Comment: Not today's date a date someone could set for the future like Jan 30, 2015, etc. It would work as so. Person submits a form with their goal and the deadline for their goal. It would then show up on an index page